How can I install a PFX certificate from the command line?
I install PFX like this:
$securePassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter the PFX password"
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "foo.pfx" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Password $securePassword

I verify that it is present:
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {
    $_.Thumbprint -eq "02C55BC23568A755E69A3479E1F8681B1CFE"
} | Format-List

Subject      : 
Issuer       : 
Thumbprint   : 02C55BC23568A755E69A3479E1F8681B1CFE
FriendlyName :
NotBefore    : 
NotAfter     : 
Extensions   : 


For some reason, an app that I use won't work. It just displays a message:
System.ApplicationException: Keyset does not exist

However, if I use the Certificate Import Wizard, it works fine.
I see an "Include all extended properties", which I don't find a corresponding command line option for, but is that relevant?
How can I compare the two certificates installed with different methods?
What other properties can I look at? I'm thinking of properties like owner, permissions, etc.
